# Proper way to setup ldap auth with aiohttp.web

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm looking for solution how to setup domain authorization with aiohttp.
There are several ldap librarys, but all of them blocks event loop, plus i don't have clear understanding about user authorization with aiohttp. 
As i see i need session managment and store isLogdedIn=True in cookie file, check that cookie at every route -> redirect at login handler, and check key in every template? It seems very insecure, session could be stolen.

Answer (score 2):

You may call synchronous LDAP library in thread pool (`loop.run_in_executor()`). 
`aiohttp` itself doesn't contain abstractions for sessions and authentication but there are `aiohttp_session` and `aiohttp_security` libraries. I'm working on these but current status is alpha. You may try it as beta-tester :)

Comment: Hello, what's the status of your project? I need to create a small aiohttp server that delegates logins to ldap.